# Unexpected theme change in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm getting unexpected behavior in the look of ggplot2. When I plot large amounts of data, it appears the default theme changes from theme_grey to something like theme_bw.  I can reproduce this on the particular dataset I'm working on, but cannot reproduce it on simulated data.

At any rate, here's the code:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = Sequence, y = y, color = as.factor(group))) +
geom_point(shape=19, alpha = 0.8)
nrow(df2)
[1] 4330
```

results in:
[image]

Now, if I take a subset of the data:

```
df3 <- slice(df2, 1:10) 
ggplot(df3, aes(x = Sequence, y = y, color = as.factor(group))) +
    geom_point(shape=19, alpha = 0.8)
```

results in:
[image]

I have tried:

- uninstalling/reinstalling ggplot2
- manually specifying a theme
- unload all packages except ggplot2
- working outside of a project

Sample of 5 obs:

```
> dput(df2[1:5, ])
structure(list(Sequence = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), group = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), y = c(7711.945, 7695.075, 3432.585, 8081.19, 7344.455
)), .Names = c("Sequence", "group", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 5L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It looks like Sequence is stored as a factor.  Do you want it to be numeric?

Comment: Could you give us an idea of your input to the plot? Perhaps with dput?

Comment: Setting `df$Sequence <- as.numeric(df$Sequence)` makes no difference

Comment: Added minimal dput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input for 'x' is currently stored as a factor (I'm guessing).  The following code will reproduce the issue you're having and the final line of converting the x to numeric fixes the issue.

```
# make some test input
n <- 5000
df <- data.frame(x = factor(1:n), y = rnorm(n), group = sample(0:1, n, replace = T))

library(ggplot2)

# Using the x "as is" which is currently a factor
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y =y, color = as.factor(group))) + geom_point(shape = 19, alpha = 0.8)
# Converting to numeric we see the desired result
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(x), y =y, color = as.factor(group))) + geom_point(shape = 19, alpha = 0.8)
```

Comment: I do not get the expected result in the second ggplot call.

Comment: Strange: I **do** get the expected result from the second ggplot if I add `+ theme_gray()`

Comment: Two questions: 
1. Are there options in R/ggplot to set a global default ggplot theme?
2. Is the issue of having different look according to whether you ahve factor vs numeric intended?

Comment: The issue actually doesn't have to do with the theme changing.  It's that white lines are used to denote each level of the factor.  Since the levels are so scrunched together it creates what looks like a white background.

Comment: Thank you! I've accepted the answer. What about global options for the default ggplot theme?

Comment: `theme_set` might be what you're interested in.  Although the default should be theme_grey unless you explicitly changed it.